# Sierpinski Triangle Inversion

Tags: python, geometry, turtle-graphics

Hey I'm trying to invert a Sierpinski's Triangle in Python for class, I'm new to python and the turtle api. I was wondering if anyone could explain how the points work in the goto function as I'm having trouble understanding how to map out the inverted triangle correctly. (This code was given to me and I have only slightly modified it).

```
import turtle

def drawTriangle(points,color,myTurtle):
    myTurtle.fillcolor(color)
    myTurtle.up()
    myTurtle.goto(points[0][0],points[0][1])
    myTurtle.down()
    myTurtle.begin_fill()
    myTurtle.goto(points[1][0],points[1][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[2][0],points[2][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[0][0],points[0][1])
    myTurtle.end_fill()

def getMid(p1,p2):
    return ( (p1[0]+p2[0]) / 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2)

def sierpinski(points,degree,myTurtle):
    colormap = ['cyan','purple','orange','navy','gold',
                'firebrick','lawn green']
    drawTriangle(points,colormap[degree],myTurtle)
    if degree > 0:
        sierpinski([points[0],
                        getMid(points[0], points[1]),
                        getMid(points[0], points[2])],
                   degree-1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([points[1],
                        getMid(points[0], points[1]),
                        getMid(points[1], points[2])],
                   degree-1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([points[2],
                        getMid(points[2], points[1]),
                        getMid(points[0], points[2])],
                   degree-1, myTurtle)

def main():
   myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
   myWin = turtle.Screen()
   myPoints = [[-200,-100],[0,200],[200,-100]]
   sierpinski(myPoints,3,myTurtle)
   myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the coords look (for when you run your code):
[image]

In your `main()`, just change the original `myPoints` from

```
myPoints = [[-200,-100],[0,200],[200,-100]]
```

to:

```
myPoints = [[200,100],[0,-200],[-200,100]]
```

[image]

Comment: No problem Ryan Hutton